# Get-Help shows `-AllUser` parameter for Remove-AppxPackage, so why won't the cmdlet won't accept it?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-store-apps, windows-server-2016, appx

I need a way to reliably remove all Appx Package from a system that start with a given string. On most systems the following works:

```
Get-AppxPackage -all MyApp* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

However for two systems I get the following:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-AppxPackage -all CDI* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Remove-AppxPackage : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AllUsers'.
At line:1 char:48
+ Get-AppxPackage -all CDI* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-AppxPackage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.RemoveAppxPackageCommand
```

This basically says `AllUSers` is invalid, but this contradicts the `Get-Help` output:

```
 Get-Help Remove-AppxPackage -Parameter AllUsers

-AllUsers [<SwitchParameter>]
    {{Fill AllUsers Description}}
    
    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                False
    Accept pipeline input?       False
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Is there a Path issue or another way to remove the Appx package for everyone?

### Update #1: Version info

Here is the version info for the command:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Command Remove-AppxPackage

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Remove-AppxPackage                                 1.0        Appx
```

And the OS

```
> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      14393  0
```

### Update #2

Module version output

```
PS > Get-Module -ListAvailable Appx


    Directory: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   2.0.0.0    Appx                                {Add-AppxPackage, Get-AppxPackage, Get-AppxPackageManifest...
```

Is there any way to produce the same effect as the `AllUsers` Switch when i don't have it (even though the documentation says i should)

Comment: My guess would be that, for some reason, `Remove-AppXPackage` cmdlet is using one of the other parameter sets that don't support `-AllUsers` (only one of three does). No clue why... You might want to double-check what's coming thru the pipeline on the problem machines.

Comment: @KeithMiller, I don't think that's the problem, because you'd see a different error message in that case. However, it is conceivable for the help information and the actual cmdlet definition to be out of sync.

Comment: @LiamKelly: Are you aboe to check what parameters are available with tab-completion.

Comment: @KeithMiller `-AllUsers` is not tab completing even when positionally it matches the `Get-Help` format  (IE: `-Package $PKGNAME -AllUser`). Other Tab complete paramters still work in the same spot

Answer (score 1):

**[`Remove-AppxPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/remove-appxpackage) has an `-AllUsers` switch only in *recent* versions of Windows (both desktop and server editions).**

- On the linked page, browsing the version-specific doc pages (via the dropdown list of versions above the list of topics on the left) shows that `Windows Server 2016 PowerShell` and `Windows 10 and Windows Sever 2019 PowerShell` are the *earliest* versions that document `-AllUsers`.

As you've stated later, you're using Windows Server 2016, and the version number indicates a recent release, so `-AllUsers` *should* work. For instance, on my recent Windows 10 release (release ID `21H2`, build `19044`; Windows 10 has the same foundation as Windows Server 2016), `-AllUsers` *is* present. A notable difference is that the `AppX` module version is `2.0.1.0` on my machine, compared to `1.0` on yours, which may explain the difference:

Your error message indeed implies that the cmdlet itself lacks an `-AllUsers` parameter - despite what the `Get-Help` cmdlet may report (the information isn't guaranteed to be in sync).

- If you want to know whether a given command truly supports a given parameter, use 
  [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) `-Syntax`, which directly consults the command's definition; in this case: 
  `(Get-Command -Syntax Remove-AppxPackage) -match '-AllUsers'`
- A simpler alternative is to try to *tab-complete* the parameter name: if nothing happens, the parameter doesn't exist.

Potential **solutions**:

- Use `Get-Module -ListAvailable AppX` to see if you accidentally have *multiple* versions of the `AppX` module installed (with an obsolete one shadowing the platform-appropriate one), and if so, remove all but the most recent one (highest version number).
- Otherwise, you can try to *manually copy* the module from a recent Windows 10 / Windows Server 2019 or a Windows Server 2022 machine - but you'll have to see if that actually works.

  - Unfortunately, the `Appx` module is *not* available in the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=appx), so you cannot simply install the latest version with [`Install-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Install-Module).
  - The need for doing this would imply that the [*docs* for Windows Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/remove-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2016-ps) are incorrect.

Comment: added an Update, is there any way to avoid scraping a more modern windows system?

Comment: @LiamKelly, there is a mysterious discrepancy in your version-info output: Your update suggests that you at least have an old version of the `AppX` module _loaded_ (imported),  because the `Version` output of a `Get-Command` reports the command's _module's_ version. This module needn't be in the standard lookup locations (which `-ListAvailable` consults), but could have been imported from a nonstandard location, by explicit path, such as from a `$PROFILE` file. To rule this out, start a PowerShell session with `powershell.exe -noprofile` , or run `Remove-Module AppX -Force`.

Comment: To spell it out: `Get-Command Remove-AppxPackage` reporting `1.0` as the version implies that it was loaded from _version 1.0 of the `AppX` module_.

Answer (score 0):

The cmdlet, like many others also, would require you to elevate the PowerShell to have admin permissions if you want to affect other users.

Comment: While that is a good point in general, it doesn't explain the OP's symptom.